# Fibonacci Heap for Dijkstra via Java

Tags: java, dijkstra

I want to implement Fibonacci Heap on Dijkstra Algorithm. I use this code for Fibonacci heap.
http://keithschwarz.com/interesting/code/?dir=fibonacci-heap
The problem is how to call the method: decreaseKey? It always give me the hint that (entry,double). But how to write an entry? The following is a simple example, how to fill the question mark?

```
FibonacciHeap<Integer> aa = new FibonacciHeap<>();
aa.enqueue(10, 1.01);
aa.enqueue(10, .2);
aa.enqueue(12, 3.2);
aa.enqueue(13, 3.4);
aa.decreaseKey(??????, newPriority);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`decreaseKey()` expects the first argument to be of type `FibonacciHeap.Entry`. 3 methods in the class return the `Entry`s of the heap:

- `public Entry<T> enqueue(T value, double priority);`
- `public Entry<T> min();`
- `public Entry<T> dequeueMin();`

Each of the 3 methods return a different element, and modify the heap in their own way. Depending on your use case, you can store these `Entry`s in a variable and pass it to `decreaseKey()`.

One such case would be storing the `Entry` while enqueuing it. Whenever you `enqueue()` something to the heap, it returns its corresponding `Entry`. From its documentation:

```
/**
 * Inserts the specified element into the Fibonacci heap with the specified
 * priority.  
 * ...
 * @return An Entry representing that element in the tree.
 */
public Entry<T> enqueue(T value, double priority);
```

You can store it, and pass it to `decreaseKey()`.

```
FibonacciHeap<Integer> aa = new FibonacciHeap<>();
FibonacciHeap.Entry entry = aa.enqueue(10, 1.01);
// ...
aa.decreaseKey(entry, newPriority);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works well, but only need to add FibonacciHeap.Entry.